# gnuradio `ImportError undefined symbol`

Tags: python, c++, gnuradio

I'm new to GNU Radio and python. I'm trying to write a correlation block, 
somewhere in my code I use fft filter:

```
gr::filter::kernel::fft_filter_ccc  *d_filter;
d_filter = new gr::filter::kernel::fft_filter_ccc(1, x_vector);
d_filter->filter(noutput_items,in_y,out);
```

I run

```
cmake ../
make
```

and it complies perfectly fine,
but when i try

```
make test
```

I'll get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
2:   File "/home/mohammad/projects/FD/implementation_tests/oot_modules/gr-full_duplex/python/qa_fd_correlation_cc.py", line 25, in <module>
2:     import full_duplex_swig as full_duplex
2:   File "/home/mohammad/projects/FD/implementation_tests/oot_modules/gr-full_duplex/build/swig/full_duplex_swig.py", line 28, in <module>
2:     _full_duplex_swig = swig_import_helper()
2:   File "/home/mohammad/projects/FD/implementation_tests/oot_modules/gr-full_duplex/build/swig/full_duplex_swig.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
2:     _mod = imp.load_module('_full_duplex_swig', fp, pathname, description)
2: ImportError: /home/mohammad/projects/FD/implementation_tests/oot_modules/gr-full_duplex/build/lib/libgnuradio-full_duplex.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2gr6filter6kernel14fft_filter_cccC1EiRKSt6vectorISt7complexIfESaIS5_EEi
1/1 Test #2: qa_fd_correlation_cc .............***Failed    1.30 sec
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This often happens when you have declared a method at the header file, but you do not implement it. For example a destructor or something else.

To find out which method it is you should demangle the undefined symbol `_ZN2gr6filter6kernel14fft_filter_cccC1EiRKSt6vectorISt7complexIfESaIS5_EEi`.

This can be done using the `c++filt` tool. For example,

`c++filt \ _ZN2gr6filter6kernel14fft_filter_cccC1EiRKSt6vectorISt7complexIfESaIS5_EEi`

In your case this symbol is an existing symbol of the GNU Radio, located in the `gr-filter` module. Each GNU Radio module creates a library, so in order to resolve the undefined symbol issue you have to link against the required library. To accomplish this you have to do the following steps:

At the `CMakeLists.txt` file of your module, specify on which components of GNU Radio you depend. In your case the `FILTER` component.

```
set(GR_REQUIRED_COMPONENTS RUNTIME FILTER)
find_package(Gnuradio "3.7.0" REQUIRED)
```

Further dependencies can be inserted, eg:

```
set(GR_REQUIRED_COMPONENTS RUNTIME FILTER DIGITAL)
```

After that you can use the `${GNURADIO_ALL_INCLUDE_DIRS}` and `${GNURADIO_ALL_LIBRARIES}` auto generated variables to properly include the proper header files and link against the appropriate libraries.
E.g:

```
include_directories(
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${CPPUNIT_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${GNURADIO_RUNTIME_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${GNURADIO_ALL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

target_link_libraries(gnuradio-howto
                      ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
                      ${GNURADIO_RUNTIME_LIBRARIES}
                      ${GNURADIO_ALL_LIBRARIES})
```

For more info refer [here](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/OutOfTreeModulesConfig).

Comment: this is the output:
gr::filter::kernel::fft_filter_ccc::fft_filter_ccc(int, std::vector<std::complex<float>, std::allocator<std::complex<float> > > const&, int)

what should I do with it?

Comment: it's fft_filter_ccc(int,vector,float*,int)  in the outptut of c++filt, but in my code its fft_filter_ccc(int,vector) , and the documation says fft_ftiler_ccc(int,vector,int=1)

Comment: @Mohammad, I think that your problem lies at the way you build the module. See my updated answer. Hope that will help you.

Comment: thank you very much :-)
 the problem is now solve,  It's interesting that I had to edit CMakeLists.txt to make it work, I thought gnuradio would do it automatically .

Answer (score 1):

Update to answer by @manos:
**As of GNU Radio 3.8+** the CMakeList.txt files have slightly changed.

The line one needs to change in the toplevel `CMakeList.txt` is:

```
find_package(Gnuradio "3.8" REQUIRED COMPONENTS blocks analog filter fft)
```

And in `lib/CMakeList.txt`:

```
target_link_libraries(gnuradio-tempest gnuradio::gnuradio-runtime gnuradio::gnuradio-blocks gnuradio::gnuradio-fft gnuradio::gnuradio-filter Volk::volk)
```

Source: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/GNU_Radio_3.8_OOT_Module_Porting_Guide