# ImportError: /usr/local/lib/libgnuradio-mapper.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2gr5blockC2ERKSsN5boost10shared_ptrINS_12io_signatureEEES6_

Tags: python, c++, linux, gnuradio

Ｉ　try to import mapper,a gr-modle,which could be find [here](https://github.com/gr-vt/gr-mapper) 
I have install the gr-mapper like:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

under the usr/local/lib when i use ldd I get these:

```
$ ldd libgnuradio-mapper.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc03a3a000)
    libboost_system.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f4ce441d000)
    libgnuradio-runtime.so.3.7.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnuradio-runtime.so.3.7.9 (0x00007f4ce4123000)
    libgnuradio-pmt.so.3.7.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnuradio-pmt.so.3.7.9 (0x00007f4ce3ed0000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f4ce3b4e000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4ce3845000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f4ce362e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4ce3265000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4ce3048000)
    libvolk.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvolk.so.1.1 (0x00007f4ce2c90000)
    libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f4ce2a78000)
    libboost_thread.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f4ce2852000)
    liblog4cpp.so.5 => /usr/lib/liblog4cpp.so.5 (0x00007f4ce2614000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f4ce240c000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000563eb8c31000)
    liborc-0.4.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0x00007f4ce218b000)
```

The ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nudt/DLD/dataset-master/transmitters.py", line 6, in <module>
    import mapper
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mapper/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from mapper_swig import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mapper/mapper_swig.py", line 28, in <module>
    _mapper_swig = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mapper/mapper_swig.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_mapper_swig', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/libgnuradio-mapper.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2gr5blockC2ERKSsN5boost10shared_ptrINS_12io_signatureEEES6_
```

I search an useful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28859517/gnuradio-importerror-undefined-symbol)
but i don't make it clearly?
Thanks in advance~

Comment: Give us more info. What version of gnuradio are you using? What's your OS? OS version?

Comment: GNU Radio Companion 3.7.9&ubuntu16.04